# Oracle SQL JSON_QUERY ignore key field

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a json with several keys being a number instead of a fixed string. Is there any way I could bypass them in order to access the nested values?

```
{
   "55568509":{
      "registers":{
         "001":{
            "isPlausible":false,
            "deviceNumber":"55501223",
            "register":"001",
            "readingValue":"5295",
            "readingDate":"2021-02-25T00:00:00.000Z"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My expected output here would be 5295, but since 59668509 can vary from json to json, JSON_QUERY(data, '$."59668509".registers."001".readingValue) would not be an option. I'm not able to use regexp here because this is only a part of the original json, which contains more than this.

UPDATE: full json with multiple occurrences:

This is how my whole json looks like. I would like all the readingValue in brackets, in the example below, my expected output would be [32641, 00964].

```
WITH test_table ( data ) AS (
    SELECT
        '{
   "session":{
      "sessionStartDate":"2021-02-26T12:03:34+0000",
      "interactionDate":"2021-02-26T12:04:19+0000",
      "sapGuid":"369F01DFXXXXXXXXXX8553F40CE282B3",
      "agentId":"USER001",
      "channel":"XXX",
      "bpNumber":"5551231234",
      "contractAccountNumber":"55512312345",
      "contactDirection":"",
      "contactMethod":"Z08",
      "interactionId":"5550848784",
      "isResponsibleForPayingBill":"Yes"
   },
   "payload":{
      "agentId":"USER001",
      "contractAccountNumber":"55512312345",
      "error":{
         "55549271":{
            "registers":{
               "001":{
                  "isPlausible":false,
                  "deviceNumber":"55501223",
                  "register":"001",
                  "readingValue":"32641",
                  "readingDate":"2021-02-26T00:00:00.000Z"
               }
            },
            "errors":[
               {
                  "contractNumber":"55501231",
                  "language":"EN",
                  "errorCode":"62",
                  "errorText":"Error Text1",
                  "isHardError":false
               },
               {
                  "contractNumber":"55501232",
                  "language":"EN",
                  "errorCode":"62",
                  "errorText":"Error Text2",
                  "isHardError":false
               }
            ],
            "bpNumber":"5557273667"
         },
         "55583693":{
            "registers":{
               "001":{
                  "isPlausible":false,
                  "deviceNumber":"555121212",
                  "register":"001",
                  "readingValue":"00964",
                  "readingDate":"2021-02-26T00:00:00.000Z"
               }
            },
            "errors":[
               
            ],
            "bpNumber":"555123123"
         }
      }
   }
}'
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(data, '$.payload.error.*.registers.*[*].readingValue') AS reading_value
FROM
    test_table;
```

UPDATE 2:

Solved, this would do the trick, upvoting the first comment.

```
JSON_QUERY(data, '$.payload.error.*.registers.*.readingValue' WITH WRAPPER) AS read_value
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you. The value 5295 is a single, scalar value in the JSON. `JSON_QUERY()` does not return such values - it returns JSON fragments. The only workaround (other than using a different function) is to use the `with array wrapper` clause, but then the output would be `'["5295"]'`, not what you reported. Are you, in fact, using `JSON_VALUE()`, not `JSON_QUERY()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant with wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in the comment to your question, if you are getting that result from the JSON you posted, you are not using `JSON_QUERY()`; you must be using `JSON_VALUE()`. Either that, or there's something else you didn't share with us.

In any case, let's say you are using `JSON_VALUE()` with the arguments you showed. You are asking, how can you modify the path so that the top-level attribute name is not hard-coded. That is trivial: use asterisk (`*`) instead of the hard-coded name. (This would work the same with `JSON_QUERY()` - it's about JSON paths, not the specific function that uses them.)

```
with test_table (data) as (
  select
    '{
       "59668509":{
         "registers":{
           "001":{
             "isPlausible":false,
             "deviceNumber":"40157471",
             "register":"001",
             "readingValue":"5295",
             "readingDate":"2021-02-25T00:00:00.000Z"
           }
         }
       }
     }'     from dual
)
select json_value (data, '$.*."registers"."001"."readingValue"'
                   returning number) as reading_value
from   test_table
;

READING_VALUE
-------------
         5295
```

As an aside that is not related to your question in any way: In your JSON you have an object with a single attribute named `"registers"`, whose value is another object with a single attribute `"001"`, and in turn, this object has an attribute named `"register"` with value `"001"`. Does that make sense to you? It doesn't to me.

Comment: This is working like a charm for the json chunk I posted at first, however, I should've posted the full one with the multiple values desired initially. I agree the "001" does not make any sense, since it's already below. However, there's nothing I can do to change the json since it's from a live system.